# Fixed-point casting 16 to 64-bits?

Tags: c, fixed-point

Fixed point conversion macros for 16-bit numbers, with max and min values:

```
#define SCALEFACTOR_16(N) ( 1U << N )
#define Q_MAX16 (  SCALEFACTOR_16(16-1) - 1U )
#define Q_MIN16 ( -SCALEFACTOR_16(16-1)      )
```

Casting min value to 64 bits:

```
int64_t x = (int64_t)Q_MIN16;
```

gives:
`x == 0x0000 0000 ffff 8000`
which is a positive number, and not what I had expected.

The solution is to change `1U` to `1UL`:

```
#define SCALEFACTOR_16(N) ( 1UL << N )
```

In this case the output is OK:
`x == 0xffff ffff ffff 8000`

Why isn't the first case working as expected? What happens during the cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1U` integer constants have type `unsigned int`. The resuting type of a shift operation is that of its (promoted) left operand, in this case `unsigned int`.

Performing the bit shifts on unsigned types is the correct way though, but after done shifting, you need to convert back to the intended signed type. Otherwise the conversion to `int64_t` won't "sign extend" the number as the compiler sees an unsigned type.

Please note that the `-SCALEFACTOR_16` is fishy for the same reason, it doesn't actually do anything, because the operand of unary minus is unsigned. When correctly converting from unsigned type to signed, the compiler will handle the sign automatically, so there's no need for `-`.

`SCALEFACTOR_16` also got a bug, you need to wrap the macro parameter in parenthesis.

Solution:

```
#define SCALEFACTOR_16(N) ( 1U << (N) )
#define Q_MAX16 ( (int16_t)(SCALEFACTOR_16(16-1) - 1U) )
#define Q_MIN16 ( (int16_t)(SCALEFACTOR_16(16-1)     ) )
```

---

You can easily make this macro quite type-generic too:

```
#define SCALEFACTOR(N) ( 1U << (N) )
#define Q_MAX(N) ( (int##N##_t)( SCALEFACTOR(N-1) - 1U ) )
#define Q_MIN(N) ( (int##N##_t)( SCALEFACTOR(N-1)      ) )
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define SCALEFACTOR(N) ( 1U << (N) )
#define Q_MAX(N) ( (int##N##_t)(  SCALEFACTOR(N-1) - 1U ) )
#define Q_MIN(N) ( (int##N##_t)( -SCALEFACTOR(N-1)      ) )

int main (void)
{
  int64_t x;
  x = Q_MIN(16);
  printf("%.16"PRIx64 " %"PRIi64 "\n", x, x);

  x = Q_MIN(32);
  printf("%.16"PRIx64 " %"PRIi64 "\n", x, x);
}
```

Comment: "The resuting type of a shift operation is that of its (promoted) left operand, in this case `unsigned int`". Which left operand did you mean is uint here?

Comment: @Danijel There is only one shift. The left operand of `1U << N` is `1U`.

Comment: OK, sorry, I thougt you were reffering to some variable, left of the `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Your system has 32 bit (`unsigned`) `int`. All the work you're performing is with 32 bit values, and you cast *after* doing the work. When you cast from `unsigned int` to `int64_t`, it doesn't change the value (it doesn't interpret the high bit of an `unsigned` as a sign bit to be extended), so it gets zero filled.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are casting a 32bit unsigned value (0xFFFF 8000) to a 64bit signed value (0x0000 0000 FFFF 8000). Casting an unsigned value to a larger type just adds 0 at the front. Casting signed value to a larger type adds the sign bit to the front like:

```
(int64_t)(int32_t)Q_MIN16; ==> 0xffff ffff ffff 8000
```